# JavaDoc @link package in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javadoc

I need to link to a package in JavaDoc.

Example:

`@param example description (see {@link com.example.packagename this})`

With the code above, I get this message:

`warning - Tag @link: reference not found: com.example.packagename`

Linking to a class in the same package works fine, but I need to link directly to the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with `@link`.

Create `package.html` file or a single `package-info.java` in your `com.example.packagename`

```
/**
 * This is packagename
 */
package com.example.packagename;
```

Then you can link to this package by using `@see`.

```
/**
 * @param example description
 * @see com.example.packagename
 */
void doWork(String example) {

}
```

Now you android studio will show the documentation as follow:

[image: javadoc]

By clicking on `com.example.packagename`, the javadoc inside `package-info.java` will be shown.
[image: packagename javadoc]

Note:
Instead of linking packagename directly, You can use `<a>` tag:

```
 * @see <a href="{@docRoot}/com/example/packagename/package-summary.html">Packagename</a>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This only works in Android Studio (using javadoc keyboard shortcut).
However, using Tools > Generate JavaDoc... I continue getting the warning and it changes the link with plain text.

Comment: @John_Dark I didn't get any error while generating javadoc maybe there is something wrong with your javadoc gradle task. but you can also use HTML tags. See my updated answer.